# Onclick popup form is going blur when clicked

Tags: html, jquery, css, popup

Whenever I am trying to click the button the popup form is coming blur, I tried solving this but I am unable to figure out the exact problem. Please find the code below which I have used:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ENQUIRE NOW</button>
      
       <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        
        <div class="modal-header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row bnm ">
        <div class="col-md-3 cnt">
            <div class="contact-info">
                <img src="https://image.ibb.co/kUASdV/contact-image.png" alt="image"/>
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <h4>We would love to hear from you !</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 cccn">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <form action="send.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="fname"> Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Name" name="fname" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phone">Mobile:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile number" name="mobile" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Comment:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Text" rows="5" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">        
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="bn btn btn-default">
                    
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

      </div>
      </div>
```

Find the website link :

http://arklan.in/

Please find enquire now button at the last section of the website.

Answer (score 1):

modal is blured because is deeply nested in other elements..

if you put it before section tag, it is ok..

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM5Cc.png)

div elements with blur effect are just after body tag..

Comment: you are asking me to add modal div outside the section?

Comment: div blur > div modal

Comment: I am not getting what exatly you are saying please tell me clearly.

Comment: put myModal inside "modal-backdrop"

div class="modal-backdrop"
div #myModal /div
/div

Comment: i think modal-backdrop is loading from bootstrap. I didnt added any modal-backdrop div

Comment: please let me know what script i have remove, i am not getting what to do

Comment: can you move the entire modal outside of the rest of your code, to the very bottom? It doesn't need to be nested in any other element, other than the body..

Answer (score 0):

you can add z-index: 100; to the element to get it over other elements

Answer (score 0):

if you cant want to change on HTML just add this CSS.

```
.modal-open .modal-backdrop.show,
.modal-open .modal-backdrop.in  {
   display: none !important;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHkIB.png